# 3G Router supports port-forwarding, but it does not work

Tags: wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, 3g

My Linux workstation is using an MTS 3G Wifi USB dongle to get onto the Internet - this workstation has no other network connection.

This Router's Port Forwarding admin page does let me specify the following set of 4 values per row:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
Config name  | Local port | Wan port | MAC  
---------------------------------------------------------
1. Service A |   8080     |   8888   | aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff
2. Service B |   9090     |   9999   | aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff
        ...
---------------------------------------------------------
```

The MAC address that I'm specifying above is the one I get from the output of `ifconfig`. (It's the `wlan1` interface that has a local IP address assigned to it by the DHCP server in the Router - that's how I recognize it.)

When I save the above values, the same admin page then shows the following **readonly** values towards the bottom:

```
---------------------------------------
Config Name    |  Port   | IP Address
---------------------------------------
 1. Service A  |   8888  |   a.b.c.d
 2. Service B  |   9999  |   a.b.c.d
       ...
---------------------------------------
```

This readonly output seems to suggest to me that `Service A` listening on local port `8080` can be accessed from the public Internet via `a.b.c.d:8888`. But I am unable access `Service A`. In fact, I cannot even ping `a.b.c.d`. (I'm aware that the Router might be intentionally disallowing the incoming ping to `a.b.c.d` but not sure what else to try.)

If I check my workstation's public IP address via a site like http://www.whatismyip.com/, I see my public IP being reported as `e.f.g.h` instead of `a.b.c.d`!

So, how am I to forward public WAN port `8888` to local port `8080` running `Service A`, and then access Service A from the public Internet?

**EDIT:**

My IP addresses are as follows:

- `a.b.c.d = 100.84.c.d`
- `e.f.g.h = 163.47.g.h`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your router is reporting an IP different to your public IP, it's likely that your 3G network provider isn't allocating you a public IP and is instead performing [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), which would also explain why port forwarding isn't working.

This is confirmed if a.b.c.d is in a private IP address range: From 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255. From 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255. From 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255.

When I encountered this issue, I called my 3G provider and they "switched me to their public network," which meant I was assigned a public IP address and could accept incoming connections. While this solved my particular issue, I've found 3G IP addresses change quite rapidly which can cause issues with software that isn't designed to support that. Using a Dynamic DNS service with a very low [TTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) like 1 (1 second) may make it usable. Or you could get a business plan with a static IP.

Comment: `a.b.c.d` does not belong to the private range (pls see the EDIT). Also, I didn't understand the "Using a Dynamic DNS service with a very low TTL like 1 ..." part since the TTL is understood in number of hops these days, not in seconds. Did you basically mean: a DDNS with high refresh/update rate?

Comment: TTL is the hop limit when talking about IP packets, but in the context of DNS it's how long in seconds before the DNS record expires and the client queries the name server again for the IP address.

Comment: Yes, the purpose of a low TTL on DDNS is to achieve a high refresh/update rate. Does the router have a status page that shows the WAN IP address? If so, is it the same as a.b.c.d or e.f.g.h? Try refreshing the router page and whatismyip.com at the same time and see if you get the same address. Also, refresh the pages often over a 5 minute period to see how quickly your IP is changing. How are you testing the port forwarding?

Comment: (1) Thanks for TTL clarification. (2) Yes, the router has a status page showing the WAN address - that's where I said I get the a.b.c.d address from. (3) This IP address remains fairly constant, in fact, until I unplug and replug the router! (4) This router even provides a DDNS option via `no-ip.com` which I'm not using since my WAN address is not changing at all during a session. But using it anyway doesn't help either.

Comment: (5) For testing, I'm a running python-based web server serving files from my Linux box. The server listens on local port `8080` on all interfaces, and I try to (unsuccessfully) connect to `a.b.c.d:8888` from same or another machine. Testing `localhost:8080` obviously works! (6) As you can see in my EDIT, `100.84.c.d` does not appear to be in the private address range.

Comment: Many routers will not forward connections to the WAN IP from a local interface. Have you tried connecting from a box elsewhere on the internet? It shouldn't make any difference on a web server, but try forwarding 8080 to 8080...I'm not sure if it's the router, protocol or server, but forwarding to the same port occasionally fixes strange issues. Does e.f.g.h change during a session or across sessions? I don't know why your reported public IP is different to your WAN IP, perhaps your provider has misconfigured their transparent proxy server.